# Display Tasks in Calendar in Lightning Experience for all Users

Tags: lightning, tasks, activities, calendar

I would like to see Tasks in my Calendar in Lightning. According to this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpZFAA0), this is delivered in Lightning Experience.

I can see that I can do it using the [Create a Calendar from Anything](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_activities_calendar_create.htm) feature, however how can I set this up for all users ? Is there a way to setup this via API ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Do you have any update on this?

Comment: No, nothing more

Comment: apparently you just need to [replace due date with a custom field](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=calendar_create_example_tasks.htm&type=5)...because...confetti